# Loading table in sqlite db using python: table not found

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python 2.7 and am trying to load a pipe delimited file into a sqlite table.

Originally I tried to bloc transactions, but ran into an "Operational Error: no such table: ff. I added the global statement in the function, didn't help either (didn't expect it to, but tried to be sure).

So removing the function call for debugging purposes, I've added the INSERT statement directly within the loop, and get the same error.

I checked: clt.db is created, and contains the table ff (empty tho). The error happens at line 64 (curs.execute(insertStmt,obs) since the linenums were edited out).

I don't know if this has any bearing on the solution or not (hope not): I'm running this on a micro EC2 instance, with the target db written to an S3 bucket mounted via s3fs. Maybe a latency issue?

--update:
I got this to work when closing both connection & cursor, and reopening them. Even after the conn.commit(). Tried time.sleep() and that didn't help, so it seems the connection/cursor really have to be closed and reopened for the new table's presence to register. Why that is I have no idea. Any advice?

Any idea? Thank you.

Aust.

```
import csv,sqlite3

dbName = 'clt.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
curs = conn.cursor()


def loadBloc(bloc):
        global conn,curs
        curs.execute('begin')
        for obs in bloc:
                curs.execute(insertStmt,obs)
        conn.commit()
        return None



createCode = '''
create table ff
(
a text not null,
b text not null,
c text not null,
d numeric not null,
e text not null,
f text not null,
g text not null,
h numeric not null,
i numeric not null
);
'''

curs.execute(createCode)
conn.commit()

nb = 10000; cnt = 0
bloc = ["" for i in range(nb)]
f = open(infile,'rt')
csv.register_dialect('pipes',delimiter='\t')
with open('ff.dat','r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,dialect='pipes')
        for row in reader:
                a    = row[0]
                b    = row[1]
                c    = row[2]
                u = c.split('/')
                if len(u) == 3:
                        v = [int(u[i]) for i in range(len(u)) ]
                        c = "{0:4d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}".format(v[2],v[1],v[0])
                else:
                        c = "1212-12-12"
                d   = row[3]
                e   = row[4]
                f   = row[5]
                g   = row[6]
                h   = row[7]
                i   = row[8]

                obs = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
                insertStmt = 'insert into ff (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) values (' + ','.join('?'*9) + ');'
                curs.execute(insertStmt,obs)
                conn.commit()

                print cnt
                #bloc[cnt] = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
                #if cnt == nb-1:
                #       loadBloc(bloc)
                #       print "=============================================="
                #       bloc = ["" for i in range(nb)]
                #       cnt = 0
                #else:
                #       cnt = cnt + 1

f.close()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Why do you say "pipe delimited" and call your (unnecessary) csv dialect "pipes" but then use `delimiter='\t'` ???

Comment: At that point the code wasn't seeing the table to write to, which was my focus. I corrected this later on, once I'd figured out that closing and reopening the connection was necessary. The data is pipe delimited.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. After trimming off all the unused code, making the remaining code a bit more terse and making `cnt` count something, it runs OK as shown below, with only one commit (just before terminating). I suggest that you try this code on a non-cloud system first, to ensure that there are no issues with Python or sqlite or csv. Then try it on the suspect instance, and others if necessary.

[ff.py]

```
import csv,sqlite3

dbName = 'clt.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
curs = conn.cursor()
createCode = '''
    create table ff
    (
        a text not null,
        b text not null,
        c text not null,
        d numeric not null,
        e text not null,
        f text not null,
        g text not null,
        h numeric not null,
        i numeric not null
    );
'''

insertStmt = (
    'insert into ff (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) values (' +
    ','.join('?'*9) +
    ');'
    )

curs.execute(createCode)
# conn.commit() # works ok without this

with open('ff.dat','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    for cnt, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = row
        u = c.split('/')
        if len(u) == 3:
            v = [int(x) for x in u]
            c = "{0:4d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}".format(v[2],v[1],v[0])
        else:
            c = "1212-12-12"
        obs = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
        curs.execute(insertStmt,obs)
        # conn.commit() # doesn't need to be inside the loop
        print "row number:", cnt

curs.close()
conn.commit() # need at least 1 commit
conn.close()
```

[transcript]

```
C:\junk\so>del clt.db

C:\junk\so>type ff.dat
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I
1|2|16/10/2011|4|5|6|7|8|9

C:\junk\so>\python27\python ff.py
row number: 1
row number: 2

C:\junk\so>\bin\sqlite3 clt.db
SQLite version 3.6.14
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from ff;
A|B|1212-12-12|D|E|F|G|H|I
1|2|2011-10-16|4|5|6|7|8|9
sqlite> ^Z

C:\junk\so>
```

Comment: The code works both locally and using EBS. The closing/reopening of the connection did help with S3 (the table was finally visible), and I thought I was out of the woods, but then I ran into various table integrity errors while loading the dat file (all leading to a process crash). I don't know why that is. Had to move on and am now using EBS volumes.

Comment: @auduf: Please consider accepting my answer (click on the tick to the left).